# extend class not found codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting this error while extending a class resides under the same folder structure.
Fatal error:  Class 'parseRestClient' not found

```
//parseObject.php
<?php
class parseObject extends parseRestClient{


//parse.php
<?php
include 'parseConfig.php';
include 'parseObject.php';
include 'parseQuery.php';
include 'parseUser.php';
include 'parseFile.php';
include 'parsePush.php';
include 'parseGeoPoint.php';
include 'parseACL.php';
include 'parseCloud.php';

class parseRestClient{
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to load in the parseRestClient class before you try to inherit from it. At the top of `parseObject.php`, try adding `include('parse.php')`.